# Axios call yields a "blocked by CORS policy" error

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I'm using Oxford Dictionaries API to validate words input by user. I'm following [the docs](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation/making-requests-to-the-api) exactly:

```
const endpoint = 'lemmas'
const languageCode = 'en'
const wordId = 'example'
const url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/' + endpoint + '/' + languageCode + '/' + wordId
const params = {
  app_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  app_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
this.axios.get(url, params).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Yet I'm getting this error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/example' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

EDIT: amazingly, even when using the [NPM package Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oxford-dictionaries-api/v/0.0.3) with the snippet they provide on their NPM page, I still get the same CORS policy issue.

EDIT(2): just tried with [another similar NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oxford-dictionary), same result.

Why, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Yes I've seen this, but Axios calls to commercial APIs are usually cross servers and it's never been a problem for me. Even my local project fetching content through Axios calls from my remote WordPress website works fine.

Comment: That's because they allow it via CORS headers.  (or because you're using Node.js rather than a browser)

Comment: OK, but then why would the API docs provide code that by default doesn't work due to this issue?

Comment: I followed the link through to the API documentation but all I see is a Python example. Is there a JavaScript example somewhere that you're following?

Comment: Nope (talking about good documentation...), but that's besides the point I guess?

Comment: @SLaks that URL doesn't provide a solution, a feeling shared by other people too (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853#issuecomment-331616519). Apparently this problem is a monumental pain in the *ss: github.com/axios/axios/issues/853

Comment: The whole point of CORS is that there is no solution; you cannot access data (from the browser) if the server doesn't let you.  You can use more-permissive server-side proxies.

Comment: Those packages were designed for Node, not the browser.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, that makes sense